# Proving $\nabla\left\{\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|}\right\}=-\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|^3}x$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: analysis, derivatives, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

As per the title, I would like to prove that

$$\nabla\left\{\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|}\right\}=-\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|^3}x\qquad\text{in }\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3).\qquad(\star)$$

Now, I am of the opinion that one would prove this in the following manner:

For all test functions $\phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^3)$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left\langle\nabla\left\{\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|}\right\},\phi\right\rangle&=-\left\langle\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|},\nabla\phi\right\rangle
\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}\int_{\|x\|>\epsilon}\frac{\nabla\phi(x)}{\|x\|}\,dx
\\
&=\cdots
\end{aligned}
$$
and then evaluating the limits.

However, I was having a debate with a friend of mine, and he claimed that you could prove $(\star)$ in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\})$ and then extend to distributions á la

$$\nabla\frac{1}{\|x\|}=-\frac{x}{\|x\|^3}.$$

Then you say that this holds in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$, i.e.

$$\left\langle\nabla\left\{\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|}\right\},\phi\right\rangle=-\left\langle\frac{x}{\|\cdot\|^3},\phi\right\rangle$$

assuming one can show that $\nabla\left\{\frac{1}{\|\cdot\|}\right\}$ is a distribution. Is this way valid?

Comment: How do you interpret $\int_{\|x\|>\epsilon}\frac{\nabla\phi(x)}{x}\,dx$?

Comment: @xpaul It's a vector valued integral, i.e. you integrate component-wise

Comment: Maybe you mean $\int_{\|x\|>\epsilon}\frac{\nabla\phi(x)}{\|x\|}\,dx$

Comment: @xpaul Yes, that is what I meant (it was a typo; my apologies!)

Comment: Would your friend also observe that for $x \neq 0$ we have $H'(x)=0$ and then extend this to distributions by saying that $H'=0$? If not, why does he want to do it in one case but not in the other?

Comment: Perhaps this calculation, although for another function, can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302734/proving-nabla-cosk-x-k-sink-x-cdot-fracx-x-in-mathcald/2302982#2302982

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your friend seems to want to say is this: consider $u \in \mathscr D ' (\Bbb R^3)$ such that $u = 0$ on $\Bbb R^3 \setminus \{0\}$; is it true then that $u=0$? Your concrete problem is just the particular case $u = \partial _i \frac 1 {\|x\|} + \frac {x_i} {\|x\|^3}$.

Well, this is not true: to see this just consider the case $u = \delta$ (Dirac's distribution). The deep reason why this extension attempt fails is because there is no natural way to *uniquely extend* distributions from an open set to an open superset. In general, the only non-ambiguous (functorial) set-theoretic operation that you can perform on a distribution is to *restrict* it to an open subset.